# Electorate badge awarded but not visible

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

I recently got the Electorate badge. But I couldn't see the gold badge next to my photo. I could see the silver and bronze badge count, but not the gold badge.

[image]

Comment: How recent? And did you see the message in your Achievement inbox, or just on your profile on the badge tracker? When I look at your profile, I only see [570 votes on questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4990460/pri?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Hi Glor, I got it half an hour before. 570 votes is my last day count. I updated the picture

Comment: And here we are, years later and I can't see the Electorate badge on the person who asked about this post. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The badge progress tracker is faster than the script which actually *awards* the badges. You'll have to wait a bit (1-24 hours), but you'll definitely get the badge. In the meantime, you can track your progress towards another badge, as you already satisfy the conditions for Electorate.

It's basically the same problem as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289486/295232).

Comment: The same problem with me, also the badge does not appear in the available badges, so I need to wait for about 24 hrs or there is something wrong with my profile?

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: Good to know it, I thought that somethig bad happened with my badge hahaa, thanks for the clarification.